# Json parsing android studio

Tags: android, json

i am facing this problem when trying to display JSON data to my phone

```
public class json extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView text1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);


}

public void button1(View v) {
    new JsonTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");
}


public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String result = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            result = buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return result;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        text1.setText(result);


    }
}
```

This is my error message

> 9-29 11:28:24.657  29264-29264/com.example.window8.myfriend
>   D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 09-29 11:28:24.657 
>   29264-29264/com.example.window8.myfriend W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42050da0) 09-29
>   11:28:24.667  29264-29264/com.example.window8.myfriend
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.window8.myfriend, PID: 29264
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.window8.myfriend.json$JsonTask.onPostExecute(json.java:83)
>               at com.example.window8.myfriend.json$JsonTask.onPostExecute(json.java:36)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-29 11:33:24.887  29264-29264/com.example.window8.myfriend I/Process﹕
>   Sending signal. PID: 29264 SIG: 9

Comment: Is your `TextView` not null? you should check it.

Comment: Your code does not seem to relate to the stack trace com.example.window8.myfriend.json$JsonTask.onPostExecute(json.java:83)  but there are only 70 lines in it

Comment: you set text1.setText(result); in onPostExecute but you dose not initialize it in onCreate so error comes NullPointerException. initialize text1 in onCreate(). text1 = findViewById(R.id.text1);

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have n't initialised your textView variable.Inside onCreate() initialise it.Then this exception won't come.Hope it might help you.

Comment: I added but still same, i am now clueless

Comment: Please paste your complete class code here , so that we can look

Comment: Thanks for all your help

Comment: Welcome,Happy coding..:)

Comment: try to see the resultcode for the provided url through debugging.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize you text view before use it.

```
public class json extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView text1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);
//you need to add this line
text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextviewId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

guys I solved it .The problem was really that, I forgotten to initialise my textview. I cant believe i made such stupid mistake (try every other thing to solve it). Thanks for all your help and and I am really sorry for wasting your time.